# What is this Ocaml code written to generate LLVM IR doing?

Tags: compiler-construction, ocaml, llvm, llvm-ir, ocamlyacc

I am new to Ocaml and don't understand what this block of code is doing

```
  let global_vars : L.llvalue StringMap.t =
    let global_var m (t, n) = 
      let init = match t with
          A.Float -> L.const_float (ltype_of_typ t) 0.0
        | _ -> L.const_int (ltype_of_typ t) 0
      in StringMap.add n (L.define_global n init the_module) m in
    List.fold_left global_var StringMap.empty globals in
```

Specifically what does StringMap.t do? what is t here? What does "global_vars : L.llvalue StringMap.t" do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntactic form `x: typ` is a type annotation which is restricting the type of `x` to a type that can be unified with `typ`.

`StringMap.t` is a type named `t` defined in the module `StringMap`.

Comment: Thanks! @octachron Is StringMap.t like another way to access the key of the stringmap?

Comment: No, it is the type of the map defined by the `StringMap` module. In OCaml, types are only used to ensure correctness of programs, they don't have any impact on the semantic of programs (at first and second approximation).

Comment: (StringMap.t is a type, so it's not really a way to access anything. I.e., it's not a function. But it's a parameterized type, kind of like (say) `[]` in the C declaration `int x[];` It tells you something about the type (that it's an array) but there is more to know about the type (namely that it is an array *of int*.). Similarly `StringMap.t` tells you that it's a map from strings to something. But there is more to know about the type: what is the type to which strings are mapped? That's the parameter, `L.llvalue ` in your case.)